# The multiprocessing python module is unable to put back the processed results

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm writing a TCP SYN scanner that checks for all the opened ports. The script is able to get all the opened ports by making use of multiple cores. At the end of the script, when trying to fetch the results using the get() method, the scripts becomes non-functional. On doing the keyboard interrupt, there appears a Traceback which is mentioned below the code. When I'm using 2 cores, the script runs fine but when loop is made to run for 3 or more times (utilizing 3 or more cores), the script gets stuck. Any suggestions on how to go further with this ?

==============Code is below=====================================

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import multiprocessing as mp
from scapy.all import *
import sys
import time


results = []
output = mp.Queue()
processes = []

def portScan(ports,output):

    ip = sys.argv[1]
    for port in range(ports-100,ports):
         response = sr1(IP(dst=ip)/TCP(dport=port, flags="S"), verbose=False, timeout=.2)
         if response:
               if response[TCP].flags == 18 :
                     print "port number ======> %d <====== Status: OPEN" %(port)

                     output.put(port)



ports = 0

for loop in range(4):
    ports += 100
    print "Ports %d sent as the argument"%ports
    processes.append(mp.Process(target=portScan,args=(ports,output)))


for p in processes:
        p.start()


for p in processes:
        p.join()



results = [output.get() for p in processes]
```

===========Output======================

```
 ./tcpSynmultiprocess.py 10.0.2.1 

WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
  Ports 100 sent as the argument
  Ports 200 sent as the argument
  Ports 300 sent as the argument
  port number ======> 23 <====== Status: OPEN
  port number ======> 80 <====== Status: OPEN
  ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
```

===========TraceBack===================

```
 ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
 File "./tcpSynmultiprocess.py", line 43, in <module>
 results = [output.get() for p in processes]
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 117, in get
 res = self._recv()
```

KeyboardInterrupt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `Queue.get()` blocks until it has data to return, which it won't if all the processes have already ended.

You can use `output.get(False)` to not block on processes that return nothing (you'll have to handle the `Queue.Empty` exception).

Or, since the queue size can also be bigger than the number of processes, you should rather use `Queue.qsize()` instead of `processes`:

```
results = [output.get() for x in range(output.qsize())]
```

Comment: Beat me to it, like 30s. Just a gotcha: it's `Queue.get` he's using. Your answer still holds though.

Comment: @alexisdm  I'm using the output.get(timeout=1) instead. Kudos for pointing it out. Don't know how I missed it. Also Queue.Empty seems to give an error. I'm posting the answer below for now.

Comment: @harveyD You don't need to use the timeout, because there is nothing to wait for at that point in the code. And you are putting the ports individually in the shared queue, so if there are 50 open ports, you should call `output.get` 50 times, not 4 times (for the 4 processes you launch).

Comment: @alexisdm  I see. Nice explanation and I'll correct it. Though (timeout =1) is working for me however there's no point using it as you mentioned. Also I got the " output.qsize " relevance. Claps.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import multiprocessing as mp
from scapy.all import *
import sys
import time


results = []
output = mp.Queue()
processes = []

def portScan(ports,output):

    ip = sys.argv[1]
    for port in range(ports-100,ports):
    response = sr1(IP(dst=ip)/TCP(dport=port, flags="S"), verbose=False, timeout=.2)
     if response:
           if response[TCP].flags == 18 :
                 print "port number ======> %d <====== Status: OPEN" %(port)

                 output.put(port)



ports = 0

for loop in range(4):
    ports += 100
    print "Ports %d sent as the argument"%ports
    processes.append(mp.Process(target=portScan,args=(ports,output)))


for p in processes:
    p.start()


for p in processes:
    p.join()



for size in range(output.qsize()):
    try: 
        results.append(output.get())
    except:
        print "Nothing fetched from the Queue..."

print results
```